# Asp.net Core IoC Typed Factory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Does ASP.NET CORE IoC have an equivalent to Castle Windsor's typed factory:

```
kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
kernel.Register(Component.For<IDummyComponentFactory>().AsFactory());
```

Or is there an example anyone knows of that achieves the same functionality?

Comment: It doesn't have such a thing, and you shouldn't need it, since [factories are a design smell](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100).

Comment: TypedFactory facility is in part of castle core (not external facility anymore) but they didnt port the castle project to asp.net core yet.

Comment: Castle core final has been released! http://www.castleproject.org/blog/2017/01/25/core-4.0.0-release/

Answer (score 3):

Probably a bit old, but if someone is looking for it, there's an "official" Microsoft implementation of the Typed Factories for DI in Asp.Net Core:

https://github.com/Microsoft/AspNetCoreInjection.TypedFactories

There's a NuGet Package as well, though it's linked to a GitHub repository that no longer exists / was moved to Microsoft (it's by the same author than the official repo, who seems to be inactive in the last year though):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCoreInjection.TypedFactories/1.2.0

I didn't use/test it, just looking for some stuff, so I can't say if it's still compatible with newer ASP.Net Core versions.